# Program doesn't find new objects in file after adding them

Tags: python, json, file, tkinter

I made this program that give value of objects (in a JSON) file that you ask for.
I made a function that adds new objects to the JSON file.
Everything works fine but when I add an object, it gets added to the file, but when I try asking for the new object it doesn't find it as if it doesn't exist, but when I check the file, I can see that the object is there.
The only thing I can do is close the program and reopen it so it recognize the added objects.
Is there a way i can make the program refresh or reopen the file so it finds the added objects without having to close/open.
Below is my code.

```
#first the program open the file 
def getjson(filepathname):
    with open(filepathname, 'r') as fp:
        return json.load(fp)

#this add new object to the file then closing it and flush so it make the changes to the file
def confirm():
    newentry = {entered_word.get(1.0, END).rstrip("\n")  : newword_def.get(1.0, END).rstrip("\n")}

    with open("dictionary.json", "r+") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        data.update(newentry)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, file)
        file.flush()
        file.close()


 root.mainloop()
 #I didn't add the rest of the script because it's all just GUI stuff and it works fine.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "try asking for the new object"?  If you are keeping the result from `getjson()` in a variable, that variable isn't going to be magically updated when you write to the file - you will need to call that function again, and perhaps do other work to update your GUI.

Comment: You don't need `file.flush()`, since closing the file automatically flushes. But you should use `file.truncate()`

Comment: @jasonharper because i run the function that ask for the objects in the file , i find the old ones but the new one that i added dont appear . i need to close and open the program .

Comment: @Barmar should i use file.truncate() instead of file.flush to make the file update for all my functions ? because when i run the function that require the file i dont get the updated file

Comment: @jasonharper ooooh i removed the variable = getjson(file) and added in inside my functions so it only set it when i run the fucntion. thank you so much i can finally finish my program

Comment: @Mrmangaka As I said above, `file.close()` automatically flushes, so it's not needed. You need `file.truncate()` either way.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that there was a Variable = getjson("file") in the script that kept the file open . so i removed it and added it inside the functions that require it . so it only open the file when i run those functions.